# replace rows with loc pandas

Tags: python, pandas

starting point:

```
    a
0   1
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   3
5   3
6   11
7   1
8   1
```

```
df.loc[df['a'] == 1,:] = df.loc[df['a'] == 1,:].groupby('a').sum()
```

ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

my goal:

```
a
0   2
1   2
2   3
3   3
4   3
5   11
6   3
```

How can i achieve that? thanks!

Comment: Can you please replace the images with the actual code values so that it's easier to help? Thanks!

Comment: changed it :) _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case no need `groupby`

```
pd.concat([df.loc[df['a']!=1], df.loc[df['a'] == 1,:].sum().to_frame().T])
Out[356]: 
    a
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   3
5   3
6  11
0   3
```

Comment: I like the trick with the concat! I think that's it? 
btw the simple groupby is just to show case my problem I need to do a more complicated operation.